# Why can you create a public alias to a private type?

Tags: d

Why is it possible to create a public alias to a private type?

I can't seem to grasp why such functionality is granted and whether it's a feature or a bug.

Take for example.

> foo.d

```
module foo;

private class Foo { }

public alias NewFoo = Foo;
```

> main.d

```
import foo;

void main() {
    auto foo = new NewFoo;

    // Foo can be used ...
}
```

I'm aware that if you don't want `Foo` to be usable then you have to declare the constructor as private and possible all members of `Foo`.

Also if there's an attempt to use `Foo` directly then the compiler complains, like I would have thought it'd do when it sees a public alias point to a private type.

I would have expected the compiler to actually disallow this kind of thing, but I guess that isn't the case.

So my question is why doesn't the compiler complain about such usage and what exactly is the reason behind this functionality?

Comment: Perhaps one of the potential use-cases is when you know ahead that the implementation will change. The only thing you have to do then is to change the alias line to `public alias StableFoo = MyNewFoo;`

Comment: The same reason many languages allow you to write a public getter/setter for a private field. This is a common practice in some communities, and occasionally there is even a good reason for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such construction lets you hide implementation of module's features and after exposing a class you aren't tied to one name - you can change it anytime you want to unless you export proper alias.

So as you can see, there's no reason for compiler to complain.